# How to vectorize a function that contain indices as variable

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

Is it possible with NumPy (1.10) to vectorize a function containing indices as variables?
I have a bool array A(i,j,k) and a second array B (bool and 3 d, too, but bigger) in which elements are supposed to get its state depending on some conditions, simplified:

```
if A[i][j][k] == True:
    B[i+1][j][k] = True
    B[i][j+1][k] = True
    B[i][j][k+1] = True
```

(so that for every element in A that is True, the elements in B that are +1 step away from the original position in every direction are set to true)

I have the feeling i cannot avoid nested loops here but i would like to (the arrays are big and execution time matters) and i would be very happy about hints how to achieve this.
(Please bear with me if the question is noobish, i am a beginner.)

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to perform [morphological dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology) in one direction.

Comment: Or even better, consider convolution/correlation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you have simplified your problem a bit too much, but as it is stated, it can be solved by generating the shifts is in all dimensions and then or everything together:

```
import numpy as np

# Test data
A = np.zeros([3,5,2], dtype=bool)
A[0,2,1] = True
A[1,4,1] = True

# Generate bigger result matrices
i,j,k = A.shape
B0 = np.zeros([i+1,j+1,k+1], dtype=bool)
B1 = np.zeros([i+1,j+1,k+1], dtype=bool)
B2 = np.zeros([i+1,j+1,k+1], dtype=bool)

# Get partial answers by offsetting A
B0[1:,:-1,:-1] = A
B1[:-1,1:,:-1] = A
B2[:-1,:-1,1:] = A

# Combine answers by oring together parts
B = B0 | B1 | B2
```

I am afraid this is not exactly what you want, though.

Comment: Yes, maybe i did :/ (e.g. the conditions are more complex and the changes are in negative directions, too, and i am not yet sure if a double true needs to be set to false again). Will test if shifting is a possibility. Need to build me a visual model for testing maybe.

Comment: I made a 3D model of the array (it is more easy for me to get a grasp of things visual) and had two realization.  1) I made two minor errors in reasoning that overcomplicated the problem in my head (so it is actually hardly simplified in what i have written in the initial post) and 2) Your solution will most likely work :). Thx.

Answer (score 0):

This works on 2D matrices:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

A = (np.random.normal(0, 1, 64) > 1).reshape(8, 8)
k = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]])
B = np.minimum(signal.convolve2d(A, k, mode='same'), 1)
```

Gives:

```
>>> A
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]])

>>> B
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

---

**One can similarly extend this for N-D matrices.**

```
from scipy import ndimage

A = (np.random.normal(0, 1, 64) > 1).reshape(8, 8)
k = np.array([
    [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
    [[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
    [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]])
B = np.minimum(ndimage.correlate(A, k, mode='constant'), 1)
```

Gives:

```
>>> A
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 0]]])

>>> B
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1]],

       [[0, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 0]],

       [[0, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 1]]])
```

*Done!*

---

An easy way to verify the correctness of the above code is to run it on matrices like this:

```
A = np.zeros((4, 4, 4), int)
A[0, 1, 2] = 1
```

This produces the desired results:

```
>>> A
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]]])

>>> B
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. Unfortunately scipy is not available for this script.